# What word means 'to cause to be hidden', especially of dissenting opinions?

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs

I think I've been using the word 'occlude' incorrectly.  I had thought that one of its meanings was something like "to cause to be hidden" or "to conveniently ignore", so one might say:

> By describing the history of boxing exclusively in terms of the star athletes, Miller occludes the significant impact the surrounding cultural paradigms had upon the sport.

or else one might say

> With the changes in the court, it became convenient to the imperial narrative that the citizens of the northern province be wealthy industrialists, and so the very existence of their homelessness problem became gradually occluded in depictions of the region.

I'm pretty sure there is a word that means what I am trying to use occlude to mean here, and it probably starts with an 'o' or something, but my googled definitions for the word don't match what I remember/how I've been using it.

Is there a different word that I might have forgotten?  Whenever I try to think of what it could be I just end up with 'obviate', but I know that means something entirely different (i.e. to make unnecessary, to get rid of). Does 'occlude' actually mean what I've been using it to mean?  If so, where can I find that definition?

Comment: Is 'obscure' what you are searching for ?

Comment: The OED defintion of 'occlude' indicates a blockage or obstruction is in view -  1. trans. To block or stop up so as to prevent anything from passing in, out, or through; to obstruct; to close (an opening, esp. an orifice or pore).

Comment: Just look up the synonyms of *conceal*. Would *mask* do?

Comment: Sadly, the verb corresponding to _obscurantism_ is the overworked _obscure_.